# ¿Como puedo subir un documento pdf al servidor en laravel 5.5?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]    $adjunto = new Adjunto;

```
$adjunto->titulo = $request->Transparencia_id;

$adjunto->Enlace = $request->Enlace;

 //obtener archivo por medio de el campo file declarado en el formulario

$archivo = $request->file('Adjunto');

 //subir archivo al servidor

$archivoName= \Storage::putfile('Archivos_Adjuntos',$archivo);

//guardar el nombre del archivo

$adjunto->Adjunto= $archivoName;      

$adjunto->save();
```

Comment: Hola Moncho, bienvenido al sitio ¿Qué problemas presenta su código? ¿ Funcionamiento erróneo? ¿ Errores? por favor añada esta descripción para comprender su problema.

Comment: Deberías añadir los errores que te devuelve, si es que te está devolviendo alguno. Además, te pongo un enlace a la documentación correspondiente a la [subida de ficheros en Laravel 5.5](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/filesystem#file-uploads), que está muy bien explicada y con suficientes ejemplos.